# How do you GET RID of localization once you have set it on a form in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, localization

I have a "minor" issue I need to address, but first off, a CATASTROPHIC problem while playing around with localization -

I changed the language on a Form to create localization resource files for several different languages to see how the localization worked...

I then FOOLISHLY deleted the VB.Net resource files for one of the languages.

This caused the Designer to no longer work, it gave an error message that pointed to code that was utterly useless in fixing, and I ended up having to restore from a backup because I could not get the designer back up and working.

I tried removing all the resource. properties that had been added to the form designer, but that didn't solve the problem.

I tried ignoring the designer warning and loading the form anyway, and managed to reset the Language property to Default, but that did not solve the error - it still wanted to see the missing language...

So my question is - what is the PROPER way to DELETE a localization resource file that won't blow up the designer...

The "minor" issue I have is I need to change the localization on the fly, just to demonstrate how the application will work in different languages by iterating through the controls on the form with:

```
        resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, New CultureInfo(lang))
```

This works fine on the CONTROLS, but it doesn't affect the objects IN the control, for example ListView Column headers. It also doesn't seem to affect the Form (Caption) itself. Only the controls ON the Form update to the language.

Not a major issue, but is there a way to get the WHOLE application display strings to switch to the localized language without having to iterate through every single object?

Thanks.

Comment: You should just revert to the last good version you committed to source control. This is a perfect example of why we use source control, even if we're just a hobbyist. Good thing you were using it, right?

Comment: The embedded resources used for Localization are stored in the Project's file. If you remove the references from there, it won't build the .resource objects and the related `.dll` won't be created anymore.

Comment: So deleting the     <EmbeddedResource Include=...> node would correct the issue?